# Is it possible to lure wolves with porkchops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've come across a [few](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/234913-so-we-can-also-lure-wolves/) [claims](https://www.armorbot.com/community/thread/7353734/minecraft-wolves-tutorial/page/2) that porkchops, when held in your hand, allow you to 'lure' untamed wolves. I assume this means that they are more likely to spawn, or will come towards you if they have already spawned near you. Is there any truth in this?

Comment: Nothing but the faint sound of dozens of minecrafters running around with porkchops...

Comment: After checking the wiki, I haven't seen any info to this effect. So, I suspect it to be false, although I can't really prove it.

Comment: @Nicholas [This](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Talk:Wolf#Pork_Chops.2FLuring) is all I could find on the wiki, and it doesn't make it any clearer whether this works or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried holding a pork chop for a while in an appropriate area, nothing spawned. Then I hunted down some wolves and stood at various distances while holding a pork chop, they didn't seem interested at all. Pork chops do not seem to have any effect on untamed wolves.

Bonus: bones don't do anything either.

[image: Holding a pork chop]

[image: Holding a pork chop]

Comment: It seems it doesn't attract wolves, but this isn't sufficient evidence to show i doesn't affect the spawn rate.

Comment: @fredley the game has been running since I posted this, holding a pork chop away from the wolves pictured here. Still nothing, if its true, I would say this is a very bad way of getting wolves. I guess the next step would be looking at the code.

Comment: Ideally there'd be some way to test against the [null hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis), but I have no idea how you'd do this in the game. It looks like code-trawling is going to be the way to go...

Comment: @fred, if you want to collect data, run through enough chunks (of land) without carrying/holding bones, counting how many wolves you see, the do the same thing while holding them out.  I'd probably start a new map with a defined seed, then cheat/`/give` the item, and run for some defined length of time (e.g. 2 days, peaceful might help)